# Christmas greetings in German for business contacts

Tags: english-to-german, letter, business-correspondence

Could someone help me to correct the following email?

*Ich wünsche Ihnen von Herzen ein frohes Weihnachtsfest und einen guten Rutsch ins neue Jahr! Ich wünsche Ihnen und Ihren Familie Gesundheit, Wohlstand und Optimismus. Ihnen und dem BOSH-Team eine erfolgreiche Geschäftsentwicklung, die Umsetzung ehrgeiziger Pläne, profitable Kunden, die Verkörperung mutiger Entscheidungen!*

What do you write in a business Christmas card? How do you email a partner for holidays?

Comment: This questions seems borderline off-topic in my opinion; it's more about writing style than anything specific about the German language. One issue that might be relevant is whether German speakers do something similar to the American style "Happy Holidays".